# Android: How can I use send data from Room to Retrofit without LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room

my situation is that I am trying to get a list of strings `List<String>` from my Room database and send it over to Retrofit to retrieve information.

I don't want to use LiveData because I would need to have a nested observer in the View to observe the data in the database and another to get the list of data from Retrofit.

I am trying to use coroutines but am unsure how to return data from the viewModelScope.launch function when it is finally done getting the values.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use LiveData because I would need to have a nested observer in the View to observe the data in the database and another to get the list of data from Retrofit.

You can define your observers as top-level classes instead of nesting them. You can do this either as a private class in the same file as the class where they are used or as a public class in a separate file. This is a good solution if your concern is an overly complex, deeply-nested, long source file. It will allow you to more easily share code if necessary.

For example, if you have the following observer in your view:

```
final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
        // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
        nameTextView.setText(newName);
    }
};
```

Then you create a named class:

```
class MyObserver extends Observer<String> {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
        // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
        nameTextView.setText(newName);
    }
}
```

and then in your view:

```
final Observer<String> nameObserver = new MyObserver();
```

If you insist on avoiding `LiveData`, you can do what you want with a `AsyncTask` or roll your own threaded implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! How would I make them into top level-classes? By overriding the methods?

Comment: @efoc You are already overriding methods, right? The biggest difference is you have to give the class a name.

Comment: Thanks for the example! I think my issue is that I don't want it to be nested. I think something like AsyncTask will work so I will look into that more!